# How to do if else if conditions in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

how to run if else if in github action step ? I am looking for an option to execute multiple if conditions in one step ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't run **if / else if** in a github action workflow job step natively (yet?) without using some code.

For example, you could eventually use `bash` to achieve what you want, something like this:

```yaml
    - run: |
        if [ ${{ github.ref }} == 'refs/heads/main' ]; then
          echo "is MAIN branch"
        elif [ ${{ github.ref }} == 'refs/heads/dev' ]; then
          echo "is DEV branch"
        else
          echo "is neither MAIN nor DEV branch"
        fi
      shell: bash
```

Comment: If one is running a workflow in multiple OS environments (E.g. ubuntu and windows), then using bash is not realistic.

Comment: You can specify the shell when using any OS to guarantee the command will be executed in the same context. On ubuntu and macos the default shell (if you don't specify it) will be bash, but on windows it will be powershell. In that case, you would have to specify `shell: bash` to guarantee it will run using it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to implement the `if/else` logic in GitHub Actions without needing another step to run some bash logic. But it is not the most intuitive.

GitHub Action support [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) with these you can construct logic that is equivalent to `if/else`.

Example:

```yaml
name: IF/ELSE Demo

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
    tags: ['*']

jobs:
  demo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DEFAULT_TAG: ${{ (contains(github.ref, 'tag') && github.ref_name) || 'dev' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo $DEFAULT_TAG
```

This would produce the following job outputs:

- When triggered via a tag, `DEFAULT_TAG` would be the name of the git tag
- When triggered via a branch or PR `DEFAULT_TAG` would be set to dev.

If the first input in `${{ (contains(github.ref, 'tag') && github.ref_name) || 'dev' }}` would turn out true, so the second arg is set as a value. If it is false it defaults back to the value specified after the logical `OR` operator.